# has_many association doesn't add column to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 tables ( TableA and TableB). A has_many Bs.

On Rails Console, the second line of this piece of code doesn't work:

```
@a = TableA.new
@a.TableBs
```

I get this error :**PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: ... does not exist**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show the code for your models for `TableA` and `TableB`. Also, note that `TableBs` is *not* an attribute or method of `TableA` if `table_a` `has_many :table_bs`. You need to read the Rails documentation regarding [active record associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Try `@a.table_bs`.

Comment: None of the rails association macros (has_one, has_many etc) add columns to the db. You need to add them yourself by creating a migration and running `rake db:migrate`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have your tables set up correctly, and you're querying a class.

Set up your associations like this:

```
class TableA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :table_bs, inverse_of: :table_a, dependent: :destroy
end

class TableB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table_a, inverse_of: :table_bs
end
```

Your corresponding migrations should look like the following:

`rails g migration create_table_as name:string`

`rails g migration create_table_bs name:string table_a:references`

`rake db:migrate`

Your `TableB` table will now have a `table_a_id` on it, which is where the association is solidified.

Now you'll be able to run something like this in your irb instance:

```
@a = TableA.new

@b = TableB.new
@b.table_a = @a
@b.save

@a.table_bs
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<TableB id: 1, name: "Foo"]>
```

**Update**

Here's a quick little explanation on `inverse_of` and `dependent: :destroy`

`inverse_of` makes associated object lookups much more performant in Rails. Without adding that to your associations, it turns out that associated Rails objects don't point to the same in-memory objects. This means that without `inverse_of`, you're always going to hit the database in order for Rails to grab the associations. If you include it, though, if the object is already in memory, Rails will just grab that object instead! It's essentially a two-way binding in memory.

`dependent: :destroy` is used on a parent object to ensure associated objects are destroyed when the parent is destroyed.

Comment: Could ou explain what do **inverse_of:** and **dependent:** mean?